# Remove a FormGroup from SonataUserAdmin in configureFormFields

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I am having problems extending the `UserAdmin` and removing a `FormGroup` within the `configureFormFields` method.

I can remove fields using:

```
public function configureListFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->with('Profile')
            ->remove('locale')
        ->end()
    ;
}
```

If I remove all fields under `Profile`, it still shows as a header. 
I tried removing `Profile` doing:

```
$formMapper
    ->remove('Profile')
;
```

But this does not work - after some research it seems remove only looks at the chidren and not the FormGroups. **What is the correct way to remove a FormGroup from the formatter so it isn't shown anymore?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a resolution to this, but it isn't very elegant:

```
$groups = $formMapper->getAdmin()->getFormGroups();
unset($groups['groupname']);
$formMapper->getAdmin()->setFormGroups($groups);
```

A better solution is more then welcome.